# why is my array_sum showing the wrong number?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array and I want to add the values:

```
$sustainCapital_arr = Array ( [0] => 2,759 [1] => 3,269 [2] => 3,481 [3] => 3,573 [4] => 3,997 [5] => 4,421 [6] => 10,999 )
```

now, interestingly array_sum is giving me an incorrect number:

```
$total_Sustaining = array_sum($sustainCapital_arr);     output: 28 ???
```

Output should be 32,499.

Now, I also tried to use a foreach loop and the same happens. What the hell is going on here?

```
$total_Sustaining = 0;
foreach ($sustainCapital_arr as $key=>$value){
                            
   $total_Sustaining += $value;
}
```

output is again 28!!!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Real numbers use dots, not commas.

Comment: great, thank you. I actually used number_format to create the array, since I wanted the array items to show up formatted. Once I took out number_format I can now see the right total. Please create answer, so that I can tick it off. Cheers

Comment: Someone else just answered. If that's the correct answer then there's no point for me to create one. My idea was that the result should be 32.499, with a decimal point, but the comma could just as well have been a thousand separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total_Sustaining = 0;
foreach ($sustainCapital_arr as $key=>$value){
                            
   $total_Sustaining += filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
```

Comment: perfect, this allows me to keep the number_format in the array creation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything is okay and working in my case with the same value, but in your array I see (,) in between digits which invalidates being an integer value
try this out

```
$sustainCapital_arr = [2759, 3269, 3481,3573,3997,4421,10999];
echo array_sum($sustainCapital_arr);
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the " , ". It was added to the array because I used number_format.